# Limit jQuery sortable list

Tags: jquery, limit, jquery-ui-sortable, max

I'm working on a project where I need to schedule persons in rooms. I'm using jQuery sortables to achieve this task. The only 'problem' is that there is a maximum capacity for a room. E.g. some rooms can have max. 3 persons, others 4 and some maybe only 1. So after browsing the jQuery documentation I came up with this.. only, it's not doing anything. The part between `onStart: function(){}` is created dynamicly by PHP.

Do you guys have some experience in setting up a max no. of items in a sortable list and check for that?

```
$(function() {
    $(".sortable, .connectable").sortable({
        connectWith: '.sortable, .connectable',
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        onStart: function()
        {

            if($(".room-1-1").sortable('items') == 2)
            {
                alert("Maximum reached..");
            }


            if($(".room-1-2").sortable('items') == 2)
            {
                alert("Maximum reached..");
            }

                        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily solved it by craeting a javascript function which checks the number of LI elements in a specified DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

First, the event you want to hook on is not `onStart`, but simply `start`, [according to the doc](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#event-start).

Then, as thenducks said, I don't think your way of counting the elements is right. You can do it whithout using sortable for counting :

```
if($(".room-1-1 items").length == 2)
{
    alert("Maximum reached..");
}
```

where `items` is the selector on the types of elements in your lists (may be `divs`, `lis`, a `CSS` class, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are just missing one piece, in Firebug, try:

```
$(".room-1-1").sortable('items')
```

You will most likely not see a number of items, but rather a collection of elements. So then, what you want is:

```
if( $(".room-1-1").sortable('items').length == 2 ) { ... }
```

Comment: I've also tried that earlier but it makes no difference... I figured myself too some sort of array would be returned. But my `alert()` never pops up.

Comment: Well, what _is_ returned? What does firebug say?

Comment: Like Wookai said, it might be that you dont want to call `sortable` on the collection in this case.